# Ruby 1.9.3:, required gem with UTF-8 chars fail to parse, how to solve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I am fighting this stacktrace and was not able to solve yet:

`` /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bugsnag-5.0.1/lib/bugsnag/sidekiq.rb:1:in `require': /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sidekiq-4.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:51: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bugsnag-5.0.1/lib/bugsnag/sidekiq.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bugsnag-5.0.1/lib/bugsnag.rb:135:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bugsnag-5.0.1/lib/bugsnag.rb:135:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bugsnag-5.0.1/lib/bugsnag.rb:133:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bugsnag-5.0.1/lib/bugsnag.rb:133:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require' ``

The source file in the gem in question contains some UTF-8 chars (`def self.❨╯°□°❩╯︵┻━┻`) but it is marked with `# encoding: utf-8`

I know that the encoding problem is only one in Ruby < 2.0 but I can't upgrade that yet. Why is the encoding header ignored here, what do I need to look for?

Answer (score 0):

encoding: utf-8 - there is an internal encoding. you need to check and setup an external encoding too if need.

for setup both of them run Ruby process like

```
ruby -E utf-8
```

or

```
ruby --encoding utf-8
```